# Apache NiFi interprocess communication

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

To separate the logic, simplify the main flow and reuse processors groups I'm looking for something to implement interprocess communication logic in Apache NiFi.

So far the only thing I was able to find is to use InvokeHTTP in the main flow and HandleHTTPRequest/Response pair in the group. However, having too many open HTTP ports may lead to security issues. Is there a better way to do the same, i.e., routing the flow file and attributes to a needed processor and then return it back? If not, I think it would be quite helpful to have route / intercept flow processors built-in in NiFi.

PS. I know that I can turn a group into a template and use it in the flow, I do not want to do that in this case. I want to be able to use the same logic in multiple flows.

Comment: Have you tried Apache Kafka?

Comment: I tried NextGen Connect which does not require layers of complexity to perform a simple task of routing data from one processor to another processor, doing something with that and returning it to the initial processor to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outpout and input port.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

> Port: Dataflows that are constructed using one or more Process Groups
>   need a way to connect a Process Group to other dataflow components.
>   This is achieved by using Ports. A DFM can add any number of Input
>   Ports and Output Ports to a Process Group and name these ports
>   appropriately.

[image]

Comment: No I cannot. I want the group not being connected to any flow at all but being able to perform the task needed to other flows.

Answer (score 0):

Inner Remote port can be used to communication between not connected processors in NiFi 1.11.x and above: [Configure Site-to-Site Server NiFi Instance](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#configure-site-to-site-server-nifi-instance)

**Send FlowFile to not directly connected process goup:**

1- Add remote process group to NiFi and connect it to current instance.

[image]

2- Add remote port to the process group, which you want to receive flowFiles.

[image]

3- Enable remote port which has been added to process group.

[image]

**Receive FlowFile from not directly connected process group:**

1- Add remote output port to source process group:

[image]
[image]

2- Add remote process group to NiFi and connect it to current instance.

[image]

3- Enable remote process group and active output port:

[image]

Comment: How do you return processed data (flow file) from the remote remote process group?

Comment: @Shamil I've updated the answer to describe how to send FlowFile to remote port.